# Running multiple config files with Bppancestor

Tags: python, shell, snakemake, bpp

I need to run Bppancestor with multiple config files, I have tried different approaches but none of them worked. I have around 150 files, so doing it one by one is not an efficient solution.

The syntax to run bppancestor is the following one:

```sh
bppancestor params=config_file
```

I tried doing:

```sh
bppancestor params=directory_of_config_files/*
```

and using a Snakefile to try to automatize the workflow:

```py
ARCHIVE_FILE = 'bpp_output.tar.gz'

# a single config file
CONFIG_FILE = 'config_files/{sims}.conf'

# Build the list of input files.
CONF = glob_wildcards(CONFIG_FILE).sims

# pseudo-rule that tries to build everything.
# Just add all the final outputs that you want built.
rule all:
    input: ARCHIVE_FILE

# run bppancestor
rule bpp:
    input:
        CONF,
    shell: 
        'bppancestor params={input}'

# create an archive with all results
rule create_archive:
    input: CONF, 
    output: ARCHIVE_FILE
    shell: 'tar -czvf {output} {input}'
```

Could someone give me advice on this?

Answer (score 1):

You're very close. Rule `bpp` should use as input a specific config file and specify concrete output (not sure if the output is a file or a folder). If I understand the syntax correctly, [this link](http://biopp.univ-montp2.fr/manual/html/bppsuite/2.2.0/bppancestor.html) suggests that output files can be specified using `output.sites.file` and `output.nodes.file`:

```py
rule bpp:
    input:
        CONFIG_FILE,
    output:
        sites='sites.{sims}',
        nodes='nodes.{sims}',
    shell: 
        'bppancestor params={input} output.sites.file={output.sites} output.nodes.file={output.nodes}'
```

Rule `create_archive` will collect all the outputs and archive them:

```py
rule create_archive:
    input: expand('sites.{sims}', CONF), expand('nodes.{sims}', CONF)
    output: ARCHIVE_FILE
    shell: 'tar -czvf {output} {input}'
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the quick response! I will try what you propose. In any case I do not know if specifying a concrete output in rule `bpp` is possible, as bppancestor specifies the output inside the config file.

Comment: Ah, this is interesting, could you point me to some documentation or examples?

Comment: This is a link to Bppsuite manual http://biopp.univ-montp2.fr/manual/html/bppsuite/2.2.0/index.html#SEC_Contents , and this link goes directly to thevBppancestor part http://biopp.univ-montp2.fr/manual/html/bppsuite/2.2.0/bppancestor.html.

Comment: I updated the answer, but not 100% sure...

Comment: I will try! Thanks in any case!